# Find most common capitalizations of MySQL column value

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two MySQL tables representing items of some kind, and the text labels that are applied to those items. It's a many-to-many mapping of items to labels, represented with foreign key relations:

```
> SELECT * FROM Labels;
+----+--------+
| id | label  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | foobar |
| 2  | FooBar |
| 3  | fooBar |
| 4  | Foobar |
| 5  | BLAH   |
| 6  | blah   |
| 7  | Stuff  |
+----+--------+

> SELECT * FROM ItemsToLabels;
+----+----------+
| id | label_id |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 1        |
| 1  | 6        |
| 2  | 1        |
| 3  | 1        |
| 3  | 7        |
| 4  | 2        |
| 5  | 4        |
| 6  | 6        |
| 7  | 5        |
| 7  | 6        |
+----+----------+
```

I want to construct a query which will give me the list of *most used* label capitalizations. In other words, I want the following result:

```
> SELECT some magic query;
+----+--------+-----+
| id | label  | cnt |
+----+--------+-----+
| 1  | foobar | 3   |
| 6  | blah   | 3   |
| 7  | Stuff  | 1   |
+----+--------+-----+
```

I know I can use `COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` to get all the rows with the same spelling but different capitalizations, but that hasn't led me to a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is the count for foobar 3 instead of 4 (alternatively, why is blah 2 instead of 3)? I don't quite understand what query you want.

Comment: The count for `foobar` is 3 because the label `foobar` itself is used 3 times, in addition to the number of times the other variations of that label are used. Honestly the count isn't that important; the vital bit is getting `foobar`, `blah`, and `Stuff` returned, while ignoring the less-common capitalizations. (And the count for `blah` is 2 instead of 3 because I typo'd.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. Huge thanks to Alex Reece for being a sounding board, and to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770936/6136080) for providing a framework for getting stable results. I've put both my final answer and my process for arriving at it below.

---

### Final Answer

```
> SELECT lc1.id, lc1.label, mc.max_cnt
FROM (
  SELECT Labels.id, Labels.label, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Labels
  JOIN ItemsToLabels
  ON Labels.id = ItemsToLabels.label_id
  GROUP BY Labels.id
) lc1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, label, max(cnt) as max_cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT Labels.id, Labels.label, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Labels
    JOIN ItemsToLabels
    ON Labels.id = ItemsToLabels.label_id
    GROUP BY Labels.id
  ) lc2
  GROUP BY label COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI
) mc
ON lc1.cnt = mc.max_cnt
AND lc1.label LIKE mc.label COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
+----+--------+-----+
| id | label  | cnt |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | foobar |   3 |
|  6 | blah   |   3 |
|  7 | Stuff  |   1 |
+----+--------+-----+
```

You can see an SQLFiddle of it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19bb0/1

---

### Process for arriving at it

#### Computing Counts

The first step was to simply compute the number of times each label was used. This is pretty straight forward:

```
> SELECT Labels.id, Labels.label, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Labels
  JOIN ItemsToLabels
  ON Labels.id = ItemsToLabels.label_id
  GROUP BY Labels.id;
+----+--------+-----+
| id | label  | cnt |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | foobar |   3 |
|  2 | FooBar |   1 |
|  3 | fooBar |   0 |
|  4 | Foobar |   1 |
|  5 | BLAH   |   1 |
|  6 | blah   |   3 |
|  7 | Stuff  |   1 |
+-------------+-----+
```

#### Getting Max Counts

Then I need to sort the labels by descending count, and from each set of labels that are spelled the same but have different capitalization grab the top one:

```
> SELECT id, label, max(cnt)
  FROM (subquery ORDER BY cnt) AS s
  GROUP BY label COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
```

That results in a query which looks like this:

```
> SELECT id, label, max(cnt)
  FROM (
      SELECT Labels.id, Labels.label, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM Labels
      JOIN ItemsToLabels
      ON Labels.id = ItemsToLabels.label_id
      GROUP BY Labels.id
      ORDER BY cnt DESC;
  ) AS s
  GROUP BY label COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
+----+--------+----------+
| id | label  | max(cnt) |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | foobar |        3 |
|  6 | blah   |        3 |
|  7 | Stuff  |        1 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

This looks right! And it is... almost.

#### Why That Doesn't Work

It turns out that MySQL doesn't guarantee that GROUP BY performs a stable sort. It is just by change / internal implementation detail that doing an ORDER BY in the subquery, followed by the GROUP BY in the outer query, results in the top-sorted row still being on top. And the `SELECT id, label, max(cnt)` statement makes no guarantees that the id and label it grabs will be from the same row as the max(cnt). For example, just changing the ORDER BY in the subquery results in the same counts being returned, but the wrong labels:

```
> SELECT id, label, max(cnt)
  FROM (
      SELECT Labels.id, Labels.label, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM Labels
      JOIN ItemsToLabels
      ON Labels.id = ItemsToLabels.label_id
      GROUP BY Labels.id
      ORDER BY cnt ASC;
  ) AS s
  GROUP BY label COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
+----+--------+----------+
| id | label  | max(cnt) |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | fooBar |        3 |
|  6 | BLAH   |        3 |
|  7 | Stuff  |        1 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

So we need a way to avoid that.

#### A More Stable Solution

Luckily, I found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770936/6136080) which explains how to do something similar to what I want. The catch is that, in that problem, the value they want the max of (timestamp) is already in the table. While in this problem, I have to compute the count.

So my first stab was to create a table containing all the information I need, and then reference it just like in that other answer:

```
CREATE TABLE LabelCounts (
    `id` INT, `label` VARCHAR(80), `cnt` INT
);

INSERT INTO LabelCounts (
  SELECT Labels.id, Labels.label, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Labels
  JOIN ItemsToLabels
  ON Labels.id = ItemsToLabels.label_id
  GROUP BY Labels.id
);

SELECT *
FROM LabelCounts lc1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, label, max(cnt) as max_cnt
  FROM LabelCounts
  GROUP BY label COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI
) lc2
ON lc1.cnt = lc2.max_cnt
AND lc1.label LIKE lc2.label COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI;
```

This gets the job done. You can see that it correctly re-calculates the correct label, no matter what the inner query returns, by JOINing on the the count being equal to the maximum count.

Unfortunately, I wasn't going to execute this in an environment where I can just create additional tables. And if I used `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` instead, I can't reference it twice like I need to in this query. So the final step was to in-line the creation of the LabelCounts table. You can see the resulting query at the top of this answer.